# Struggling to find the right regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm struggling to find the right regex to validate an input.
I need a regex to match an alphanumeric string which ends with 9 digits, no more, no less.
All the spaces and special characters are stripped before the check, they don't matter here.

Examples of what I need :

**SHOULD MATCH :**

- perpignan123456789
- DEINOjeonfjuefz123456789
- a123456789
- 123456789

**SHOULD NOT MATCH :**

- perpignan1234
- 123456789fdazda
- perpignan1234567890123456

I think I'm close to the solution with : `[A-Za-z]{0,}[0-9]{9}$`

The problem is that it returns "true" when tested with : perpignan1234567890123456

Some help would be appreciated,
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Use `^[A-Za-z]{0,}[0-9]{9}$`, you just missed `^` anchor to make sure the string starts with your pattern. See https://regex101.com/r/aUlMNX/1/.

Comment: I can't understand your rules. Can you briefly explain them?

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
[A-Za-z]{0,}[0-9]{9}\D
```

Comment: OP just needs to match the whole string. No need for fancy patterns when anchors do the job.